# Mac OS X, passwd, and keychain

Tags: password, keychain

As far as I'm aware, `passwd` doesn't change the keychain password on Mac OS X. Is there a way to do this properly from the command line with a single command? If not, what about with multiple commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `security set-keychain-password`:

```
$ security set-keychain-password
Old Password:
New Password:
Retype New Password:
$
```

The password and keychain can also be specified as arguments:

```
security set-keychain-password -o oldpassword -p newpassword file.keychain
```

Comment: Hmm, is the argument variant safe?  I would be concerned about the passwords being visible e.g. in the output of `ps auwwx`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. I assume, too, that you can use the keychain file argument with the interactive version. And I agree, the other version isn't as safe, Although for batch scripts it'd be more convenient.

Comment: Note: to get this method to persist after restart, you need to go to Keychain preferences and uncheck the boxes "Synchronize login keychain password with account" and "Set login keychain as default" (OS X 10.10)